# Название закрытых членов класса и аргументы конструктора

Tags: c++

```
class Point
{
public:
    Point(double x, double y) : x(x), y(y) {}
private:
    double x, y;
};
```

Я понимаю, что код рабочий, и вопрос, возможно дурацкий.
Вопрос заключается в законности совпадения названий закрытых переменных класса и аргументов конструктора. Просто вид инициализации `x(x)` меня несколько смущает.
Собственно, 1-й вопрос: соответствует ли данный код стандарту?
И 2-й вопрос по поводу стиля: не лучше ли с точки зрения именно стиля (если ответ на 1-й вопрос положителен) назвать `private` переменные как-нибудь вроде `x_, y_` и можно ли будет в этом случае написать следующий код:

```
class PointBis
{
public:
    PointBis(double x, double y) : x_(x), y_(y) {}
    double x() const { return x_; }
    double y() const { return y_; }
private:
    double x_, y_;
};
```

И вроде я понимаю, что нет общепринятого стандарта стиля кодирования на C++, но все же...

Comment: В целом, ответ получен, галочку ставить, пожалуй, не буду, ибо обоим не поставишь. Плюсик поставил обоим ответам. Как-то его можно (нужно) закрывать?

Comment: Выбери какой-нибудь ответ и поставь галочку. А закрывать ничего не надо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно стандарту C++ (12.6.2 Initializing bases and members):

> 2 In a mem-initializer-id an initial unqualified identifier **is
>   looked up in the scope of the constructor’s class** and, if not found
>   in that scope, it is looked up in the scope containing the
>   constructor’s definition....

То есть в этом конструкторе

```
Point(double x, double y) : x(x), y(y) {}
                           ^^^   ^^^
```

идентификаторы `x` и `y`  ищутся в области определения класса.

Что касается идентификаторов, используемых в выражениях инициализации, то согласно тому же разделу стандарта C++

> 13 Names in the expression-list or braced-init-list of a
>   mem-initializer **are evaluated in the scope of the constructor** for
>   which the mem-initializer is specified.

То есть неквалифицированные имена в выражениях, используемые для инициализации идентификаторов в списке инициализации ищутся внутри области определения самого конструктора. Параметры конструктора скрывают имена членов класса внутри тела конструктора.

Например, если вы хотите, чтобы член класса `y` вычислялся как сумма значения члена класса `x` и параметра `y` в вышеуказанном конструкторе, вы можете написать

```
Point(double x, double y) : x(x), y( Point::x + y) {}
```

или

```
Point(double x, double y) : x(x), y( this->x + y) {}
```

Хотя для данного простого конструктора конечно было бы проще написать

```
Point(double x, double y) : x(x), y( x + y) {}
```

то есть не использовать член класса `x` в выражении инициализации.

Что касается стиля, то как раз такой стиль, когда имена параметров конструктора совпадают с именами членов класса, делают код более понятным. То есть сразу видно, какой параметр для инициализации какого члена класса предназначен.

Что касается использования подчеркиваний, то это очень плохой стиль программирования. Например, мне приходилось работать на терминале, где подчеркивание в идентификаторе сливалось с подчеркиванием всей строки, либо с разграничительной линией или с мерцающим курсором, что делало данные подчеркивания трудно различимыми.

Кстати сказать, это наглядный пример, когда не следуют повторять бездумно то, что делают некоторые авторы книг, как, например, Герб Саттер, который любит такие подчеркивания. Когда вы "подрастете", как специалист, и начнете думать самостоятельно, то вы поймете, что не все, что пишется в книгах, следует воспринимать на веру.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ссылку на стандарт. Именно то, что я хотел увидеть собственно, потому что 2-й вопрос, очевидно однозначного ответа не имеет. А что касается "повторять бездумно", учитывая, что я закончил институт еще в СССР, то с этим как раз проблем нет, просто не могу для себя определиться, что мне ближе.

Comment: @andy.37 Нет проблем. Спрашивайте еще.:)

Answer (score 2):

На всякий случай напоминаю, что поля инициализируются в порядке их появления в структуре, а не в порядке перечисления при инициализации.

По-моему, без подчёркиваний лучше.

Comment: Подчеркивания можно заменить на `x_m, y_m`, где m от 'member'. Во всяком случае с такими стандартами я встречался.

Comment: @andy.37: Майкрософт когда-то пропагандировала наоборот: `m_x`.

Answer (score 2):

Само по себе совпадение имен параметров конструктора и полей - вполне нормпльная вещь. Есть в этом даже своя красота.

Но задумайтесь вот над чем. Во втором варианте кода вы добавили методы-получатели с именами x и y. А как вы назовете эти методы в первом варианте ?

Comment: Да, это сильный аргумент в пользу второго варианта. Во втором варианте вполе можно определить методы `getX` и `setX`, но это, конечно, не так элегантно, что-ли)

Comment: Красивее всего эмуляция свойств решена в C# :)

Comment: @VladD угу. Так красиво, что уже абсурдно... Свойства в итоге пихают даже туда, где отлично подошли бы поля. :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Что поделать? Да и в классы часто пихают то, что должно быть лямбдой. Всяким инструментом надо уметь пользоваться.

Comment: @VladD, при желании можно сделать свойства и на плюсах :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, поля не подойдут, потому что они не могут быть частью интерфейса. Но jit-компилятор всё замечательно оптимизирует и замеры показывают абсолютно одинаковые время выполнения с полем и с автосвойством.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Смотря что называть свойствами. Какое-то приближение — наверное, да, но будет либо странный синтаксис, либо странная семантика.

Comment: @VladD, синтаксис. Немного с классом похимичить и должно получиться.

Comment: @Qwertiy не всегда интерфейсы необходимы. Ну нахрена свойства в DTO?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, потому что сериализатор умеет только свойства есть. И байндинги везде только со свойствами работают - не с полями.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Потому что свойства — это интерфейс, а поля — это «внутренности», подробности имплементации. Если вы решите поменять backing store, свойство можно оставить и конвертировать/вычислять на лету, а открытое поле — катастрофа.

Comment: Тут можно устроить целый холивар по поводу плюсов, шарпа, джавы и пр. но нужно ли? Каждый язык хорош по-своему, и у каждого есть свои минусы. В частности, мне очень нравится цитата из Ларри Уолла: "Перл считает, что вы не полезете в чужой дом потому, что это некрасиво, а не потому, что на окнах есть решетки" (Это к катастрофичности открытых полей). За точность цитаты не ручаюсь, но смысл верен.

Comment: @andy.37, проблема не в этом. Есть разница между полем и свойством, вплоть до того, что один и тот же код с полем компилируется, а со свойством нет. Это означает, что последующая замена поля на свойство не обладает обратной совместимостью не только на бинарном уровне, но и на уровне кода. А такого всегда стараются избежать.

Comment: @andy.37: Ну, Перл — это Перл, а вот если в проекте больше одного программиста, то представление о том, куда можно лезть, а куда нет, должны где-то документироваться. Поскольку сопровождающие документы всё равно никто не читает, то лучшая документация — это сообщение компилятора об ошибке.

Comment: @andy.37: А если в проекте вы сами, и держите все правила в голове, то можно и все переменные глобальными делать, разницы нет.